# Named parameters in anonymous Clojure functions?

Tags: clojure

I am learning about closures in Clojure and this function confused me:

```
(defn inc-maker
  "Create a custom incrementor"
  [inc-by]
  #(+ % inc-by))

(def inc3 (inc-maker 3))

(inc3 7)
; => 10
```

As a JavaScript developer I couldn't figure out how the argument `7` was getting passed in because in Javascript you would have to write it like this:

```
const incMaker = incByX => incByY => incByX + incByY;

const incThree = incMaker(3);

incThree(7);
```

So my question is, and not that I'm wanting to turn Clojure in to Javascript, but is there a way to name parameters in anonymous Clojure functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be a little more verbose about how you declare your anonymous function.

```
#(+ % inc-by)
```

is actually expanded to an equivalent form such as

```
(fn [n] (+ n inc-by))
```

If you use `%1`, `%2` etc, the expanded function will have more parameters.

[You can find some example on this documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fn)